Allow external resources in Apache Fop
We have upgraded from Apache Fop v2.3 to v2.9. In one template, we embed an image in a SVG in order to have round borders.
<fo:block font-size="0pt" text-align="center" space-after="12pt" space-before="{$coverTopSpace}"><!-- Font-size=0 prevents space after graphic -->
  <xsl:if test="../meta/coverUrl">
    <fo:instream-foreign-object xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <svg:svg width="1.5in" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <xsl:attribute name="height"><xsl:value-of select="1.5 * number(../meta/coverUrl/@aspect)"/>in</xsl:attribute>
          <svg:defs>
            <svg:clipPath id="roundedCornersClip">
              <svg:rect id="roundedCorners" width="100%" height="100%" rx="3.5pt" fill="none" stroke="#C5D0D9" stroke-width="0.5pt"/>
            </svg:clipPath>
          </svg:defs>
          <svg:image height="100%" width="100%" clip-path="url(#roundedCornersClip)">
            <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
              <xsl:value-of select="../meta/coverUrl"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </svg:image>
          <xsl:if test="../meta/coverUrl/@border">
            <svg:use xlink:href="#roundedCorners"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </svg:svg>
      </fo:instream-foreign-object>
    </xsl:if>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>

After the upgrade, Apache Batik is complaining.

The document references a external resource (https://sampleurl.com/test.jpg?w=l&d=standard) which comes from different location than the document itself. This is not allowed for security reasons and that resource will not be loaded.

I have seen the page about security: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/scripting/security.html 
I've also seen that there is a option on the org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.SVGConverter#allowExternalResources, which would allow embedding the image. However, this option can only be set when you have access to the object or when you start it via command line.

For me it looks like this option cannot be changed directly using FOP.
